# How to encrypt data sent by <a href>

Tags: html, jsp

I am a beginner in web development.
I have code to send data to another jsp page via the ( `<a href = "">`)
When the message appears, the data sent is displayed in the address bar of the browser
How to hide this data from appearing in the browser bar

```
<a href="page2.jsp?x=<%=S.ID() %>"></a>
```

In browser I see:

```
http://exapmel/page2.jsp?x=12
```

I want hide or encrypt ("x=12")

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt the number 12?  The number 12 doesn't seem like sensitive information, and users are likely already familiar with numbers.  Can you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve?  What sensitive information are you trying to hide, why do you need to hide it, and why are you putting it on the page in the first place?

Comment: First, I put the number 12 for example. The problem is that when there are many records, the user has access to certain records with a certain number only.

It can, through the number shown in the browser (eg 12) change to (15) This record does not have the authority to enter it

Comment: What you want to is called [Security Through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). The proper solution is to check on the server side (in your web application), whether the logged in user has access rights to the record s/he has requested.

Comment: @AliHayoti: Then you're doing it wrong.  Security is not determined when you display the URL to the user.  Security is determined when the user *requests* that URL.  If the user is requesting access to a record they aren't supposed to see, return an error.  This all happens on `page2.jsp`, *not* here.